# Using same session for different domains in chrome

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session

I have 2 web applications and 1 web service application in asp.net (all of host in same server but all have different domain) (example : 213.74.99.50:9090 for 1 st app, 213.74.99.50:9091 for second and 213.74.99.50:9093 fro web services)

I want to use same sessions for all applications.

Login at first web app then second app get login data from webservices.

I am using StateServer mode, same keys for machinekeys, also make all app name same in global.asax

There is no problem for internet explorer.  Everythings works fine. I can use same sessions at all applications.

But when I try this in chrome or firefox I have to use "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*"

But this is not working for webservices. Web applications use same sessions between them. 
Bur web services cannot use same sessions in chrome and firefox.

This is my code:
   Store session  with first application;

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["deneme"] = TextBox1.Text;

        Label1.Text = Session.SessionID;
    }
```

Read session with second application

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Label1.Text = Session["deneme"]!=null?Session["deneme"].ToString():"yok";
                Label2.Text = Session.SessionID;
            }
```

Return  Session with web services

```
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        [ScriptService]
        public class SesDeneme : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {

            [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
            public string HelloWorld()
            {

                return (Session["deneme"] != null ? Session["deneme"].ToString() : "yok") + "____" + Session.SessionID;

            }
        }
```

---

For using same session with different applications I also change web configs of all apps.

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
                  cookieName="SCS_01"
   stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
   cookieless="false"
   timeout="20"/>



    <machineKey decryption="Auto"
                decryptionKey="XXXX"
                validation="SHA1"
                validationKey="YYYY" />
```

And make all app names same with global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string applicationName = "MySiteName";

                            FieldInfo runtimeInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                HttpRuntime theRuntime = (HttpRuntime)runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
                FieldInfo appNameInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, applicationName);
            }
```

After all this I can use same sessions with all applications in internet explorer.

But using Firefox and chrome I also add web configs of all apps

```
<customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaders>
```

This way I can use same session with web applications but it is not work for web services.

Is there any way to solve this problem

I noticed something.
If I call web service directly from chrome (not from web applications) session works fine.
but if I call webservice from jquery.ajax method cannnot reach sessions.

I think Jquery ajax using different cookie key in chrome.